# problem installing oppenni_kinect stack

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect", i get the following message:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-diamondback-openni-kinect : Depends: nite-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Can anyone help??
Thx in advance..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10020/problem-installing-oppenni_kinect-stack/) by [Rorsak](https://answers.ros.org/users/573/rorsak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-23**:
Can you give us more information? Which version of ROS are you installing? What sort of system are you installing it on? Version numbers will help us, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by running

**sudo aptitude install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect**

It lets you choose how to resolve these dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Susanne Thierfelder](https://answers.ros.org/users/613/susanne-thierfelder/) with karma: 26 on 2011-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1